# "Go To Definition" from User Control in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My project has a directory (e.g. `~/custom/`) for User Controls (ASCX files) or custom pages (ASPX files), which do not exist as part of any Project in my Solution, but which make calls to routines and objects in the Solution (all in C#).

When I used Visual Studio 2008, I could still browse the source code of these files and jump to internal (in-Project) code with a simple "Go To Definition", but now that I've upgrade to Visual Studio 2013, whenever I select "Go To Definition" from one of these files, Visual Studio takes me to the "[from metadata]" class view.

I have tried some of the steps from [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/837037/393280), but most of the questions deal with using "Go To Definition" from code in one Project to another Project, so the solutions don't apply to my scenario.

How can I use "Go To Definition" from custom code into Project code?

Comment: Have you seen this one yet

http://stackoverflow.com/q/13203346/3618774

Comment: I have seen it. In my case, I am opening the unmanaged file in the context of the Solution, but seemingly not any particular Project.