# How to exclude inherited members from Microsoft online api/class documentation

Tags: msdn, microsoft-documentation

When browsing Microsoft class documentation, I would like to be able to hide inherited members (i.e. inherited properties and methods). Often, I find myself looking at intermediate abstract base classes to see what specific functionality they add, and I "can't see the forest for the trees" - as the handful of new methods/properties introduced by that particular class get lost amongst them many methods/properties inherited from base classes.

For example, see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2

It is difficult to see just the methods specific to ScrollableControl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the 'triangle' to the left of `Scrollable Control` at the left side of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol?view=netframework-4.7.2 (under the `Search` box).

Click `Fields` / `Properties` etc (on the **left side** - not on the right). They are the fields / properties etc that are specific to `ScrollableControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an direct answer to the online documentation but for the usabillity:

I prefer to inspect classes directly in Visual Studio. With the help of some extensions we can go directly through <kbd>F12</kbd> to every class and parent of it (that way you don't see the parent elements of the class you are looking to).

Personaly I use Resharper ([see more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28714155/2441442)). But it seems, there is also a free extension called [Ref12](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SchabseSLaks.Ref12).

That way you can inspect the summaries without leaving your IDE and also have the source code for it available, which could be interesting sometimes.