# How to export event in a DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, delegates

I have the following two classes:

```
public class DLLClass {
     public delegate void dllDelegate(Object sender, EventArgs e);
     public event dllDelegate dllEvent;
     .....
}

class AppClass {
     DLLClass dll;

     public AppClass() {
         dll.dllEvent += new DLLClass.dllDelegate(dllEventHandler);
     }
  
     public void dllEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e){
     }
}
```

Each one is a part of the same solution, but refer to different projects.

The problem is that the compiler says that there is no `dllEvent` member in the `DLLClass`.

**EDIT:**
The error:

> error CS1061: 'AppNamespace.DLLClass ' does not contain a definition for 'dllEvent ' and no extension method 'dllEvent ' accepting a first argument of type 'AppNamespace.DLLClass ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> error CS0426: The type name 'dllDelegate' does not exist in the type 'AppNamespace.DLLClass.ParametersPanel'

Also when I try to see the definition of the `DLLClass` from the code of `AppClass`, MSVS shows me class definition from metadata with no delegates in it.

Comment: Does the compiler find `DLLClass`? You said that it only complains about `dllEven`.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn, yes it finds.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error?

Comment: Maybe you have several copies of DLLClass? One of them has the event, and another one don't.

Comment: Everything you have posted is correct, so you have omitted something here.  Create a new solution with assembly and console app and see if that works.

Comment: probably not the exact problem, but aren't you missing a constructor call for you `dll` field before trying to assign to the `dllEvent` field?

Comment: Further to alex' comments: You could also try putting in the exact and full namespace for your DLLClass delcaration (ie don't rely on using statements)

Comment: @user2134198, no there is a constructor.
Tried namespaces. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this one link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837037/go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-only-brings-up-the-metadata).

The problem was in the `.csproject` file.

Answer (score 1):

If your reference is not a *Project Reference*, but a file reference, you may need to build the first project first. Form the **Build** menu, select **Rebuild All**.

If that doesn't help, you may have referenced to the wrong file. Remove the reference to the first project, and add a *Project reference* to it.

Comment: Maybe you are not recompiling the project that contains DLLClass, because project is deselected in build configuration. Try to rebuild specifically the project with DLLClass.