# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JwtTokenViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core web application with Visual Studio 2015. I have added a reference project and implemented the method which is working fine.

Here is the screen shots

[image: error details]

Now I have removed the dependency from `project.json` and deleted the `project.lock.json` file. I have completely removed the reference.

When I completely remove the reference I am still able to use **UserViewModel** and **Go to definition** opens the file in metadata. But I cannot use the **JwtTokenViewModel**.

The error details

**error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JwtTokenViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

I did some research and found that we  get cs0246 error is due to reference problem. I have followed the solution of some link but not a solution

[Why am I getting error CS0246: The type or namespace name could not be found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854308/why-am-i-getting-error-cs0246-the-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found)

How can I resolve this issue. Please anyone let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Go To Definition" in Visual Studio only brings up the Metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837037/go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-only-brings-up-the-metadata)

Comment: I have remove the reference But still it is showing the defination from meta data Why

Comment: @SanJaisy You can find the YourProjectName.csproj or .xproj in your project directory.

Comment: yes I found the .xproj but there is nothing to edit. Can you help me out