# VS Go To Definition for C++/CLI type decompiles code instead of going there

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c++-cli, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

- My VS2022 solution has many C# projects and one C++/CLI project
- Everything targets .NET 6
- The C# projects refer to the C++/CLI project via a project reference.  They have build dependencies on it too.

Yet, when I am in C# code and I right click on one one of the C++/CLI types and choose "Go to Definition", instead of taking me to the actual code, Visual Studio decompiles it for me.

I would expect VS to realize the type in question is in the same solution and just go to the C++/CLI code.   Is there any way to "help" it realize what to do?

Comment: Is the cli project referenced as a project or as an assembly file? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837037/go-to-definition-in-visual-studio-only-brings-up-the-metadata

Comment: It's a Project Reference

Comment: Not possible, the IntelliSense provider for C++ is drastically different.

Comment: As @HansPassant points out, the C+ IntelliSense is quite separate from C# but I can recommend using Visual Assist for this (wholetomato.com). I use their Alt+G (GoTo) feature extensively and it's able to cross C# and C++/CLI. Just a happy customer.. also, it's a commercial product but IMO, pros don't economize on their tools.

Comment: @jschroedl.  Thank you I did not know that.  And I already use Visual Assist so that's for the win!